# Implementing WS-Security at the Application Level

Tags: java, soap, jboss, jax-ws, ws-security

I'm trying to build a soap service based on JAX-WS (using JBoss AS 7.1.1) and I need to implement security as well. The data is going to be sensitive, so it will be over HTTPS. However, I need to identify the client, and make sure that only they can perform operations for their organization.

From the looks of it, all I have seen on the JBoss documentation (and other JAX-WS providers documentation) indicates that multiple .xml files need to be edited (some at the app server layer).

I'm really looking for a way that I could just have a class in my service called with the SOAP headers, and I could perform the validation/authentication/authorization there. Would really appreciate someone being able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

- You can always send authentication data explicitly along with the **request** (user and password, for example, in addition to the normal arguments). You have to make sure that the connection is encrypted.
- You can refine this by using **public/private keys**: So first the server sends its public key, the client encrypts the user/password with that public key, and the server can decrypt it using its private key. As this might be too expensive on a request basis, the server could issue a **token** for a certain time which the client can send in the following requests (so a token is a means to establish a **session**).

That being said, and I know how cumbersome JBoss security setup is sometimes, you have to implement and **test** it very carefully, otherwise you might open some **security holes** (tokens may leak, sessions might be captured, token invalidation, SSL connection is terminated in web server, clear text passsword remains in RAM and is paged out on the disk  etc.).